# Method Not Allowed (POST) in django

Tags: django

I use axious for requests But I get this error

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashbaord/Menu/editStatus 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

**myscript.js:**

```
     let changeStatus = (id, place) => {
        axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
        axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'editStatus',
            data: {
                'tes1': 'test',
                'tes2': 'test'
            },
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log('dsdsdsd')

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
path('editStatus', EditMenuItemStatus.as_view(), name="edit_status_item")
```

**views.py**

```
class EditMenuItemStatus(BaseDetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Why do you want to user POST request ? `DetailView` base class does not allow POST request (normally, it is a view for displaying detail objet with a simple HTTP GET request). And without passing the CSRF token, Django will be return error. so I cannot be a good solution I think ?

Comment: When I use the function, I get an error again..
How can I pass the ccsrf?
Is the method I am using wrong?

def edaitStatus(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return  HttpResponse("hello world")

    else:
        pass

Comment: Why do you want to use a Class based view of django normally using for HTTP GET displaying information? In this case, I will do a API endpoint for my AJAX requests, why you do not ?